# RGBA4444 texture becomes black box on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm planning to use RGBA4444 texture to reduce memory usage on iPhone, but to my suprise, the created texture is always a black box on screen, same code works fine on Win10. here is the code i use to create RGBA4444 texture :

```
{
    const int texSize = 256;
    vector<unsigned char> bytes(texSize * texSize * 2, 0xFF);

    GLuint id = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA4, texSize, texSize, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, &bytes[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}
```

I'm totally at a loss, RGBA4444 is natively supported by iphone right?

tested on iPhone5s and iPad3, both are black boxes.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that the internalFormat is incorrect:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D
    , 0
    , GL_RGBA4  // <---- should be GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGBA4 on iPhone
    , texSize
    , texSize
    , 0
    , GL_RGBA
    , GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4
    , &bytes[0])
    ;
```

On Win10, it works fine when internalFormat is GL_RGBA4 (GLAD, es2.0), but acoording to this [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml), the acceptable internalFormats are GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, so even on WIN10, the correct internalFormat for RGBA4444 still should be GL_RGBA.